# Setting a SESSION variable directly from a POST value

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I have a two forms which add data to a database. The first form asks for basic details (name, email, phone, etc) and stores them. Further down the line the user can add options to their account (for example receive a newsletter, recieve promotions, etc)

This second form uses a session variable to verify who the user is: when they login or signup, their email address is set to a session variable like so:

```
$_SESSION['buyer_email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

However all of my data which is submitted to the database uses PDO which sanitizes it before it is submitted, so my question is:

Is the above line of code safe to use? it hasnt been sanitized as such, and although I cant think of anything off the top of my head are their any ways this direct POST -> SESSION could  be manipulated?

Would it be better to submit the data using PDO and then retrieve the email from the database and set that returned value as the session variable or is this overkill and needless?

Comment: Best of all you don't trust user input and check if you have a correct email (format) in `$_POST['email']` before setting it as session variable.

Comment: Anywhere that you use the value placed into the session is a problem. RULE #1 - Validate Input, Escape Output.

Comment: So your saying I should do *something* with the post value (as I suspected!) - As im doing all the normal stuff to the email address (eg the format, the PDO thing, etc..) then it makes sense to set the session variable from the value that made it through the checks and  into the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you are going to use `$_SESSION['buyer_email']` - like displaying it. To avoid issues like cross-site scripting, etc.. you should always escape it then use it.

Comment: No, the session variable will only be used for verification - any data about the user that is displayed will come from the database.

Comment: So validate it, escape it, send it to the database, then retrieve it from the database and set the session variable to it. This way the stored email address will be identical to the session variable (and will be safe of course) so it can be used to identify who the user is by looking the session email up in the database?

Comment: If the value is just going to set there unused, then there is no reason to escape it. However, it is a good practice to. This way later on the road you decide you want to display it it would be safe to.

Comment: Ahh come across a related problem! I cant retrieve the email from the database because I dont have any reference to the email address of that user! (previously I was using the preset session variable in a query "select where email = session variable". I presume I have to escape it and do the stuff PDO does manually and set it that way, or is there another way of retrieving it from the database??

Comment: You let PDO do the SQL escaping for you by using placeholder values, and you should do HTML escaping to prevent XSS *only* when rendering it on a page with `echo`. Otherwise leave it in a raw form.